# Socket.io client keeps reconnecting on Heroku, React with node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I have deployed my web app on Heroku and while everything works fine, the websockets keep disconnecting and reconnecting to the server, resulting in broken message passing between sockets (for example, if a socket is in a room and reconnects, they are no longer in that room).

I have found many questions having a similar problem to mine and it was usually a problem with the port not being set up correctly. Furthermore, in localhost, the websockets do not reconnect and everything works fine.

This is my server code:

```
// .../express/app.js
const app = express();
// routes and app config
module.exports = app;

...
// index.js 
const app = require('./express/app');
const cors = require('cors');
const sequelize = require('./sequelize');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    },
    transports: ['websocket']
});
...
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Express server started on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

And the client code:

```
var socket = io({transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false})
// I have also tried with reconnection: false but it is not what I want as it handles just one event 
// and then disconnects. I want the socket to stay connected until the user logs out (or closes the 
// browser
```

The logs on Heroku:

```
2021-01-25T19:14:44.748545+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/EIO=4&transport=websocket" host=ad-hunter.herokuapp.com request_id=b91ec827-5706-49b0-b94f-0e2938850110 fwd="82.23.237.64" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=110087ms status=101 bytes=129 protocol=https
2021-01-25T19:14:46.365100+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket" host=ad-hunter.herokuapp.com request_id=78876cd4-7159-4bb1-abe5-f3ca65e9369e fwd="82.23.237.64" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=110082ms status=101 bytes=129 protocol=https
2021-01-25T19:15:12.941661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket" host=ad-hunter.herokuapp.com request_id=e2cbc234-695b-4403-95ad-1dcb8b5b520e fwd="82.23.237.64" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=60006ms status=101 bytes=129 protocol=https
2021-01-25T19:15:16.705544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket" host=ad-hunter.herokuapp.com request_id=edf6c087-bb19-4f83-afea-6099e6dc1132 fwd="82.23.237.64" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=135127ms status=101 bytes=129 protocol=https
2021-01-25T19:15:35.975365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket" host=ad-hunter.herokuapp.com request_id=d22930dd-1b05-454d-86e8-447a95d1ae56 fwd="82.24.37.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=85068ms status=101 bytes=129 protocol=https
```

The network requests: 
[image: Network Requests]

And in chrome's console (this keeps repeating): 
[image: Console logs]

These are my thoughts so far: I understand that the server socket pings the client sockets to see if they are still active, but why do they reconnect on Heroku and not on localhost? Does Heroku refresh the server or client in some way? 
What I want is to have just one consistent socket for every client session (a socket connects to the server each time the user logs in).

Note: The play game functionality only works with a corresponding chrome extension (this is my final year project and it is very experimental).

Comment: well status: 101 means switching protocol and you spesificly said that there is not gonna be an upgrade. Probably trying to reconnect since it cannot upgrade =) Just remove upgrade: false from client and remove transports from both side. Let me know if it's working that way :) 
Oh bdw make sure both versions are 2 or 3 on client end server.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried every variation of upgrade/transport mode and nothing seemed to have worked but I finally know why, my internet connection was the problem (hence the reconnects).

Comment: I see hope then your problems are fine after all but i can really suggest that removing upgrade and transports. It's arranged by socket auto. =)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have removed them now and it is working fine. Thanks for your suggestion, as I imagine having both transport methods is more efficient and can support more clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have finally figured out the problem accidentally. So as far as I could tell my internet was working fine and I had no reason to expect that the reconnects were due to my internet losing and regaining connection.

However, I tried downloading a song and the download would fail every time (network error) which meant that my internet was problematic. I set up a mobile hotspot and now everything works as it should. This is also explains why everything was working fine in localhost.